# Actualización Angular 11 a 12

Tags: angular

Tengo una app en Angular 11 (Ap1), con algunos módulos como ng-bootstrap, ng-paginate, ng-select, y alguno más, ahora tengo que crear otra app (Ap2), mi pregunta es:

-Desinstalo angular 11,instalo angular 12 y actualizo Ap1 a angular 12 y luego creo la Ap2 con angular 12?

o

-Dejo Ap1 en angular 11, NO desinstalo angular 11, instalo angular 12 y creo la Ap2 en angular 12.

Lo que no entiendo bien, mi ap1 es angular 11 dentro de su carpeta no? si instalo angular 12 tengo que desinstalar angular 11?
Si instalo Angular 12, puedo crear también una app Angular 8 si quiero? muchas gracias

Comment: Cada proyecto puede usar una versión diferente: las dependencias se descargan en el directorio local (al proyecto) `node_modules`. Pero no sería mala idea usar la misma versión de angular en los dos proyectos. Puedes consultar cómo actualizar [aquí](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: Lo ideal sería usar la misma carpeta node_modules, eso ya seria monorepo, pero es otra historia. Al final actualice y me daba error una librería, ng-select, me arriesgue y hice la actualización con --force, corri el ng serve y se queda haciendo el build y no termina nunca, da algunos errores el ng-bootstrap, parece que esas librerías piden veriones de angular 11, al final tuve que hacer un reset del git y volver a la versión 11.